# Is it OK to have a GFCI downstream of a standard circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I would like to extend a standard electrical circuit to the outside with a GFCI outlet. Can I install a GFCI downstream? This would be easier than running a new circuit back to the breaker panel.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can certainly do this. Other options include replacing any outlet upstream with a GFCI, or replacing the breaker with a GFCI breaker. In both these cases, the entire circuit would be protected.

Comment: One thing to look out for is a shared neutral; you can use a GFCI with a shared neutral, but you can't protect downstream outlets unless they have a dedicated neutral from the point of the GFCI onward.

Comment: My understanding is that GFCI's only protect downstream, not upstream.

Comment: GFCI receptacles only protect devices connected to the LOAD side terminals. If the receptacle is installed incorrectly, downstream devices can be left unprotected. GFCI devices **do not** protect upstream devices, they only protect the circuit connected to the LOAD side terminals.